# Multiple event loop on websockets asyncio server example

Tags: python, concurrency, websocket, python-asyncio

I've a trouble understand the reason for the below code, hope someone can shed some lights on this. I'm new in async programming.

This is from [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) documentation

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
import websockets

async def echo(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    websockets.serve(echo, 'localhost', 8765))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I have some questions about asyncio design and how I can take advantage of this.

First of all, looking at the last two lines. If I understand correctly, shouldn't run_until_complete shutdown after finished its work? How can the second loop kept it alive with no jobs submitted into the loop?

Secondly, I was trying to build a back_end that can process some data from the front_end using websockets and return the calculation in realtime. There will be two kinds of tasks, one is bit longer that need computation power a bit but will happen one time for a session, and bunch of streaming data processing that need to be send back immediately (90 frames per seconds).

For the bigger tasks, should I just fire up another websocket server that process the longer work, and use the main websocket to consume on it? Or use another process to do the work in a chained async function? And for the smaller tasks, what would go wrong if I do the same as above?

TLDR:

1. Async programming is hammering my brain.
2. Maintain a nonblocking session
3. Which process hard work and light work simultaneously
4. The light work should have zero latency
5. The hard work should be as fast as possible but not effecting the light work.

Thanks!!

Comment: You're trying to ask multiple questions in one. That doesn't work well with the format of SO. Edit your question to just focus on the first thing, and then you can write separate questions that focus equally on the other things you need to do.

Comment: For your first question: one common reason for this idiom (I don't know if it applies to this library!) is graceful shutdown. To actually do graceful shutdown cleanly, you need to do something like create a stop event (future), set a signal handler to fire that event, wrap the server in an `async with …serve(…): await stop`, then `run_until_complete` that wrapper, reset the signal handler, and `run_forever`. But it turns out that, at least for some nice libraries, and if you don't care about Windows, just doing the `run_until_complete` followed by `run_forever` is enough for it to mostly work.

Comment: The other common reason is much simpler: some server functions just spawn an acceptor function and then return once it's going, so you can `run_until_complete` that server function to get the actual acceptor coro, then do any setup you need, then `run_forever`. (For that design, you can do graceful shutdown with a _third_ `run` call, by having a signal handler just fire `loop.stop`,  then call `acceptor.close()`  and restart the loop.) Here, you're not doing any setup, or touching the acceptor coro in any way, but (if this is the library's design), it is being returned by `run_until_complete`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll look a bit more on gracefully shutdown.
For the latter question, I've found that assign the task via ensure_future and only check it up if desired will make my main loop unblocking while have the ability to handle background tasks.